# When you call safeSdk.executeTransaction, what gas price is used?

Tags: gnosis-safe

If I want to execute gnosis transactions via the safe-core-sdk, what gas price is used when "executeTransaction" is called with no option parameters? I would like to know this so I know if I would need to provide custom gas prices to make my transactions faster.

Answer (score 1):

The one your web3 library (web3.js or ethers) sets, the SDK doesn't set the gas price